# What "fleio" means?

Tags: significado

What does the word "fleio" mean in Portuguese?

I see the word used from time to time on twitter for instance:
http://twitter.com/rmedeirosx/status/648601169355505664

But I wasn't able to find the meaning anywhere.

Comment: Looking quickly over a Twitter search, many seem to be replacing the letter R with L in other words, which points to the possibility of [freio](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/freio), maybe imitating the speech of foreigners or those with speech problems. Others seem to be inserting the letter L in words for no reason, which could point to [feio](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/freio).

Comment: Can we contact one of them and ask them?

Comment: An asian foreigner might pronounce "freio" that way.  As a Brazilian, I have never heard the word before.

Comment: Apenas um chute, mas não seria uma tentativa de adaptar para o português a gíria inglesa [*fugly*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Fugly)? (muito embora não se encaixe no contexto dado como exemplo... uma gíria regional talvez? tem outros exemplos?)

Comment: @mgibsonbr Escreve uma resposta, indicando isso como um possibilidade e não como uma certeza. :)

Answer (score 6):

The specific word *fleio* is derived from either *freio* or, more rarely and somewhat strangely, *feio*, and there are basically two general reasons a Brazilian might intentionally shift a R by a L.

The first one involves the famous [Turma da Mônica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monica%27s_Gang) character [Cebolinha](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cebolinha_(personagem)), a young boy who shifts R by L every time he speaks, due to his dyslalia. Recently, the meme [CHOLA MAIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=peA6xbaBMBk) has given a boost on jokes and some NSFW Twitter pages involving him. As a matter of fact, Cebolinha speaks *feio* normally, so people trying to impersonate him by *feio* -> *fleio* are actually doing it wrong.

Secondly, the person might be imitating a baby (for example, a couple doing baby talk) or, more rarely, someone with dyslalia.

The original tweet you posted is somewhat curious in that it is derived from *feio*, but it is not explicit on if this is a inside joke or a baby-like talking. Other tweets with *fleio* fall on either preceeding cases as far as I can tell, so it would be better if you added a couple more examples you have in mind.

---

There is actually another very common reason. There are "jokes" about Asian, especially Chinese people, not being able to pronounce the R sound. Most often, these use the expression *pastel de flango*.

Comment: Acho que pelo contexto tem mesmo de ser **feio**.

Answer (score 1):

That's a typo. The word is "feio" that means "ugly". Well, unless it's a new twitter slang that these young people use nowadays. But that's definitely not a Portuguese word.

Comment: http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/fleio

Comment: Não entendi.

"Palavra não encontrada. Se procurava uma das palavras seguintes, clique nela para consultar a sua definição."

Comment: Quase te enganei :P Era só para provar que não existe mesmo, convém ter uma referência :)

Comment: Não conhecia esse site. Obrigada =]

Comment: Nurdagniriel é o dicionário de português online mais bem conceituado.

Comment: I doubt it's a simple typo, because the letter L is far from the F and the E on a keyboard.

Comment: Well, it's not a Portuguese word either. As I said, maybe it's a slang, and if so, it's a new one.